# AngularJS $http.post and get using a path

Tags: python, angularjs, http

I am trying to do a basic UI where the admin user can make CRUD operations in mongoDB. I am using angularJs, html and python.

The issue is, I am not familiar with python that much and I cannot get the angular code to interact with the python backend. I am more familiar with C# and MVC, and I basically want to do the python equivalent of the following call,

```
$scope.searchStudents = function () {
    $http.post('/Admin/searchStudents', JSON.stringify($scope.stu))
    .then(
    function successCallback(response) { ...... });}
```

So when I give the function name to angular like this, I cannot call the function. In MVC, this works without a problem. Internet says make API calls but this is definitely not something I want to do. If you have any ideas, I will appreciate the help.

Comment: your js code shouldn't have to change at all whether you have a C# MVC server or a Python backend.  What exactly is the issue?  Can you provide an error message?  It seems like the issue is on your server side, not the front end

Comment: I do not have an error, I just cannot make the frontend access the backend python code, i.e cannot communicate. I think this is about difference of routes in mvc & pyhton

Comment: what does your python backend look like?  because your front end code looks fine, as long as the route `/Admin/searchStudents` is setup in your web api

Comment: I do not know how to route a relative path in my web api, how would I do that?